# ¿Cómo añadir a un Tab de un Action Bar un Spinner?

Tags: java, android, xml

Estoy intentando añadir a un Tab de un Action Bar un Spinner cómo la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me quedo en el intento...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo compartir el código XML/JavaAndroid, pero es el mismo que ofrece el asistente de Android Studio para la creación de un ViewPages con Tabs, añadiéndole un RecyclerView con CardView como contendido.

He probado con [este tutorial](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/actionbar-appbar-toolbar-en-android-iii/) que se acerca pero no lo logro, que pasos debo seguir para lograrlo?

Comment: Dddenis, tengo que salir pero rapidamente te comento por experiencia, el usar el actionbar para agregar otros elementos es un poco limitado, crea tu propia bar con Toolbar. :)

Comment: Está bien, gracias. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yo dejaría un dialogo que mostrara el avance, ademas es útil en tareas asíncronas.

te pongo un ejemplo que encontre aqui, espero te sirva y mucha suerte:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pd = null;
private Object data = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Show the ProgressDialog on this thread
    this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...", true, false);

    // Start a new thread that will download all the data
    new DownloadTask().execute("Any parameters my download task needs here");
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
     protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
         Log.i("MyApp", "Background thread starting");

         // This is where you would do all the work of downloading your data

         return "replace this with your data object";
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
         // Pass the result data back to the main activity
         MyActivity.this.data = result;

         if (MyActivity.this.pd != null) {
             MyActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
         }
     }
}
```

}

Saludos.